# SQL - If table entry exists then

Tags: mysql, sql

What I am wanting to do is if there is an entry in "player_shops" for the account ID then have a specific where clause, otherwise have no where clause. If that makes sense. Here is my code:

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(acc.gold_coins + shop.gold_coins) AS total_gold
  FROM accounts AS acc
     , player_shops AS shop
 WHERE acc.acc_id = shop.acc_id
 GROUP BY acc.acc_id
 ORDER BY total_gold DESC
 LIMIT 100
```

I want that WHERE clause to only be there IF the is a player_shop entry for the specified account ID.

Any help?

Comment: What DBMS are you using please?

Comment: DBMS? Not sure exactly what you are asking, but I believe it is mySQL5

Comment: DBMS stands for Database Management System. So, MySQL 5 is a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better use JOIN.

```
SELECT *,
   SUM(acc.gold_coins + IF(shop.gold_coins IS NULL, 0, shop.gold_coins)) AS total_gold
FROM accounts AS acc
LEFT JOIN player_shops AS shop
ON acc.acc_id = shop.acc_id
GROUP BY acc.acc_id
ORDER BY total_gold DESC
LIMIT 100
```

I'm not sure about IF syntax. It depends on what db you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL try this:

```
WHERE acc.acc_id = COALESCE(shop.acc_id, acc.acc_id)
```

Comment: COALESCE will give first null value right then use of this function here will not give desired output... it seems like in ansewer he wants to get output as LEFT outer join.... @Barry - please verify what i am saying.. in simple join you will not get null value..(NULL can be there but this is database entry only then you able to get null)..

Answer (score 0):

You should **ALWAYS** avoid using a Cartesian product in an SQL query whenever you can. Instead of joining the tables `accounts` and `player_shops` like that (with a comma) you should probably look into `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which might indirectly solve this problem for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, `SELECT`ing `*` when you select from more than one table or when you have a `group by` clause is meaningless and will issue an error only.

I think that you want here a LEFT JOIN:

```
 FROM accounts AS acc
 LEFT OUTER JOIN player_shops AS shop
   ON shop.acc_id = acc.acc_id
```

shop.acc_id will be filled with NULL if there is no record.